# oracle query which selects grouped data

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't handle with SQL statement and I have to ask you for a help.
Table contain 3 column:

```
COlumn1   Column2   Column3
12345       1        Sometext1  
23456       1        Sometext2
34567       1        Sometext3  
45678       2        Sometext4
56789       2        Sometext5
```

I'm trying to write a query which select a data like:

```
12345   1   Sometext1
12345   1   Sometext2
12345   1   Sometext3
23456   1   Sometext1
23456   1   Sometext2
23456   1   Sometext3
34567   1   Sometext1
34567   1   Sometext2
34567   1   Sometext3
45678   2   Sometext4
45678   2   Sometext5
56789   2   Sometext4
56789   2   Sometext5
```

Generally 1 row looks:

```
COlumn1   Column2   Column3
**12345**       **1**        **Sometext1**  
23456       1        **Sometext2**
34567       1        **Sometext3**  
45678       2        Sometext4
56789       2        Sometext5
```

And so on...

Comment: So you want all combinations of Column1 and Column2 per value of Column2? (effectively squaring the number of rows per Column2 value, 3 -> 9, 2 -> 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, this is what you need:

```
SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t2.Column3
FROM your_table t1 join your_table t2 on t1.Column2=t2.Column2
```